# Java object getter and setter good practice

Tags: java, object, setter, getter

I'm a little bit confused about how to properly use getter and setter in some case.
Let's imagine for example a class named `Car`.

This `Car` has a `maintenanceBook`, and this one some information about the `Car`:

```
class Car() {
    MaintenanceBook maintenanceBook;
}

class MaintenanceBook() {
    String date;
    String lastCall;
}
```

What is the best practice to access to the different parameters of the `maintenanceBook`:

- set all parameters to `public` and use `car.maintenanceBook.date` or...
- implement getter and use `car.getMaintenanceBook().getDate();` ?

Comment: This should help - [Java Getter and Setter Tutorial - from Basics to Best Practices](http://www.codejava.net/coding/java-getter-and-setter-tutorial-from-basics-to-best-practices)

Answer (score 3):

You should prefer:

- Getters and setters over the public parameters - these allow additional functionality as validation is.
- Final parameters set with a constructor with getters only, if possible - a step towards the immutability.

Also, I prefer printers over getters in general. Moreover, it's not a good idea to generate getters/setters right upon creating a class but only and only if you need them (Hibernate mapping is an exception, for example).

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with java it self. It's about the encapsulation concept which is fundamental in all object orientated languages. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_(computer_programming))

So according to this fundamental concept `car.getMaintenanceBook().getDate()` is the the right solution.